# Missing header from Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm getting error while compiling qt project which #include's < qvaluelist.h > that this file cannot be find, yet I'm finding on qt website documentation for this header.
How to solve it?

Comment: Give. More. Information.

Comment: Which Qt Version? Which header?

Comment: sorry, I've typeded <qvaluelist.h> and this hasn't been displayed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This (and its friend QPtrList) are deprecated in Qt 4. You probably have Qt 3 code.
Look here: [Porting to Qt 4](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.0/porting4.html#qvaluelist-t)
You can either link with the QT3 support library in Qt 4 or replace it with QList.